# How to enable all default emacs key-bindings on the online programming editor on `hackerrank`?

Tags: browser, safari, editor, key-bindings, rich-text-editor

I am using `Safari` version 13.1.1. macOS `Catalina` 10.15.5.

Today I have spent 8 hours in `hackerrank` unable to cut a line using `Ctrl+k`, it is so difficult when you get used to a keybinding and unable to use it for a long time. I have faced with same error on the editor on stackoverflow, which has an [answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397599/2402577). When I tested other default key-bindings some other also does not work.

- `Ctrl + k` does not work to delete a line
- `Ctrl + Space` does not work to select a line
- `Ctrl + _` does not do undo, I cannot even to redo
- `Ctrl + s` does not do forward incremental search
- `Ctrl + i` does not do indent

... and many more.

As an alternative solution, I wrote it on my local editor and copy it from there and paste it to the editor.

---

On the online editor at `hacker-rank`, it is mentioned that it provides `Emacs` as editor mode, but it does not let users to use all the main keybinds. Same issue occurs on the `leetcode` as well. You can see the example editor in these sites for [letcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/), [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-arithmetic-operators/problem).

**[Q]** How can I enable all default emacs key-bindings on the online programming editor on `hackerrank`? Can I overwrite its `.emacs` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried out and putting the emacs configuration the editor allows me to use Ctrl+K as a shortcut for deleting the line. I think you already know how to enable the emacs use, but just in case press the little engine on the top rigth corner and in editor mode choose emacs.

It doesn't seem that will allow you to change keybindings, so honestly I would rather go for writing the code in my local text editor and copy-pasting once it is written.

Comment: Hm it does not work on Safari but it seems like working on Opera

Comment: me2. I go bonkers when my fingers start emitting emacs keystroke uncontrollably. (My wife gets scarred by my yelling ;^). Pleeease, someone git this to stack overflow!